Why would Spring introduce transactions when databases have powerful transactions?

Think about concurrency when doing data-intensive applications, and use transaction isolation to solve this problem. But consider that there are transactions in both Spring and the database. But lack of experience, do not know how to choose which kind of business.


What is the difference between Spring and database transactions?
Which part they focus on and how to choose the two technical solutions?

I hope you can give me some advice or answer my confusion. Thank you very much?

The documentation would be a good place to start.  It's more comprehensive than any answer you're likely to get here.

Spring doesn't introduce transactions, it provides a unified and delcarative approach to mark your transactional boundaries. That saves you from manually starting, stopping and error handling in each method that would need it. Underneath it will still use the DB for the transaction (or whatever transactional resource you are using).

Wow, thanks for the advice.@JohnBollinger,@M. Deinum.I think I know what this surface means. But regarding marking transaction boundaries, maybe I'm not familiar enough with the documentation or the underlying layers. I'm going to try some more experiments later. Or find some code examples on the web.
